# Not able to convert PDF document to HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf

I was trying to convert PDF document to HTML using following [library](https://github.com/mgufrone/pdf-to-html) but it converting entire PDF document to image. It is creating few html pages as well but that seems blank.

Below is my code :

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Gufy\PdfToHtml\Config;

// change pdftohtml bin location
Config::set('pdftohtml.bin', 'C:/poppler-0.68.0/bin/pdftohtml.exe');

// change pdfinfo bin location
Config::set('pdfinfo.bin', 'C:/poppler-0.68.0/bin/pdfinfo.exe');

// initiate
$pdf = new Gufy\PdfToHtml\Pdf('file.pdf');

$html = $pdf->html();
```

Comment: Could you add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the start of your file and see if there are any errors?

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov ctually the PDF which i was trying to convert is actually an image and that is converted into the PDF......May i know how can i convert this image to HTML now?

Comment: I would suggest using another library, this one looks abandoned, and it looks like it failed the last build.  To answer your question, the problem you are having is caused exactly by the PDF file being originally an image. Normally, pdf is a well structured document, but when you have just an image, you can't copy the text, can't edit it. It is an image. I would suggest trying another pdf file, that has content other than an image.  Then please tell us if you still have an error.

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov I tried with the other PDF doc and it got converted properly without any error